# How do I get to the Abyssal Depths

Tags: path-of-exile

The new Abbys league has a challenge to beat the "Abbysal Depths"? How do I get into this area? If I kill all the things that spawn from an abbys it just results in a chest after a couple spawning pits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see an abyssal crack in the floor, if you open it, this crack will spread. If you kill enemies coming out of that crack fast enough, it will spread further. There are two possible outcomes, if you successfully finish it: an abyssal trove or the entrance to the abyssal depth.

So far it seems you haven't been lucky with the depths, but sooner or later this should spawn instead of the chest.

Comment: Yea, All I've gotten until now is those chests.

Answer (score -3):

Found this vid useful for abyss basics

Got mine randomly during leveling when I was about 45+ lvl

Comment: Can you summarize what it is in the video in your answer?